# how to find this web address in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have a question about express.js. Recently, I'm writing a small project. but how to route to "http://localhost:3000/upload/t/t" like this. I can only navigate to localhost:3000/upload

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please provide a [mcve] if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just make Get Request as per below.

```
var app = express();
app.get(['/upload/t/t'], function (req, res) {
      //Write your code.
})
```